# Block scroll on Modal open

Tags: fullpage.js

I'm working on this [website](http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/), (Built using [Fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) plugin). In the first section I have a modal window (by clicking on the **orange** **+** symbol).

As you can see, if you scroll with the mouse when the Modal is open, you can scroll to the next page.

How can I block this? **I need to make it scrollable ONLY when you close the Modal.**

PS: I am using **Wordpress** if this could help...

EDIT: i tried this

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).on('click', '.ts-awesome-plus', function() {
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
$.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false);
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: You apply scroll with javascript? with what function? you can don't apply scroll function when Modal is open!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the modal box is open you need to disable the scrolling with `$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false)` and also the keyboard scrolling `$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false)`. On modal close just enable them. Here is a working example, click on `Modal Open` and `Modal Close`.

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'],
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
});

//adding the actions to the buttons
$(document).on('click', '#turnOff', function() {
  $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
  $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false);
});

$(document).on('click', '#turnOn', function() {
  $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
  $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(true);
});
```

```css
.section {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}
/**
Fixed button outside the fullpage.js wrapper
*/

#turnOff,
#turnOn {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 20px;
}
#turnOff {
  left: 20px;
}
#turnOn {
  left: 240px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>

<button id="turnOff">Modal Open</button>
<button id="turnOn">Modal Close</button>


<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">One</div>
  <div class="section">Two</div>
  <div class="section">Three</div>
  <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
```